# Excel linked data and sorting

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have 2 spreadsheets.
spreadsheet 1 is the master data spreadsheet
spreadsheet 2 reads columns A, B, C & D from spreadhseet1 and populates columns A, B, C & D of spreadsheet 2..

I then write data to columns E & F in spreadsheet 2.

all works well, until someone sorts the data in spreadsheet 1.

when I open spreadsheet 2 the first 4 columns have changed to reflect the sorting that occurred in spreadsheet 1 but the manually entered data in columns E & F of spreadsheet 2 have remained where it was typed, ie it did not move with the sorting.

how can I fix this folks?
many thanks for any help with this

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you provided the formulas you are using in the sheets however from your question it sounds as though you are simply using something like this in cell A2 of 'Spreadsheet2':

`='Spreadsheet1'!A2`

This means that whatever is in cell `A2` in 'Spreadsheet1' will be in cell `A2` in 'Spreadsheet2'.

The best way to link two spreadsheets is using a static column of unique ids alongside an [INDEX/MATCH](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/214142) function so that regardless of the position in 'Spreadsheet1' the values will be matched up with the unique ids.

For example if your unique IDs are in Column A of both spreadsheets you could use this formula in cell `B2` of 'Spreadsheet2':

`=INDEX('Spreadsheet1'!B:B,MATCH($A2,'Spreadsheet1'!$A:$A,0))`

Comment: Hi thanks for the comments, I think  you may have misunderstood my problem. my problem is that I enter data into spreadsheet 2-column E. when spreadsheet 1 is sorted then the 4 columns in spreadsheet 2 automatically sort to match spreadsheet 1. So if I am linking 4 columns from spreadsheet 1, A, B C & D... & then I enter data in spreadsheet 2 - column E then the data in column E will not move to the new sorted row. I need to ensure that when data is entered into spreadsheet 2 then that data will move rows if any sorting is done on spreadsheet1. at the moment it is not.